# Is there no way to obtain sender's emailId from outlook calender data using Microsoft.Office.Interop , c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, interop, outlook

I want to get the sender's emailId.

I am able to read all the data of calender by the below code but not the sender's emailId.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook = new Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);
string currentUserEmail = oNS.CurrentUser.Address;
string currentUserName = oNS.CurrentUser.Name;
// Get the Calendar folder.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder objMAPIFolder =oNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
//Get the Sent folder
MAPIFolder sentFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);

Items sentMailItems = sentFolder.Items;

Items items = objMAPIFolder.Items;        

foreach (object item in sentMailItems)
{     
    if (item is MailItem)
    {
        MailItem oneMail = item as MailItem;        
        string mailContent = oneMail.HTMLBody;

        //item.sender is not available
    }    
}

foreach (object item in items)
{  
    if (item is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)               
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem mitem = item as     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        string subject = mitem.Subject;
        DateTime start = mitem.Start;
        DateTime end = mitem.End;
        string body = mitem.Body;
        string location = mitem.Location;
        string entryId = mitem.EntryID;   

        //sender email id not available   
        //string senderEmail = mitem.sender;
    }
}
oNS.Logoff();
```

But in any case whether reading appointments or sent folder emails, I am unable to obtain the sender's email Id.

does anybody have any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the name from `mitem.organizser` and then look at the `Recipients` to find the match..

Then look up the email address via a mapi property `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` using a `PropertyAccessor`.

Answer (score 1):

**AppoitnmentItem.GetOrganizer()** is not necessarily the sender of the appointment. In a shared calendar (chief/secretary), they might be different.

You can get the sender from an appointment using
**AppointmentItem.SendUsingAccount**

But from my experience (outlook 2010), that property returns null unless you are logged in as the sender. But it is useful to check if the organizer is different than the sender anyway.